# How to replace only a part of div text

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML

```
  <h1 class="headerLogo headerLogoWith"><span class="headvendnametext">Pick</span><br>
     <i class="headloctext">Location Name <span class="headscreentext">ScreenName</span></i></h1>
```

I want to replace only the Locationame part and the ScreenName text ,

I tried this way

```
   $('.headloctext').text('Mylocation');
   $('.headscreentext').text('myscreen');
```

when i ran the above the screen part is completely lost

http://jsfiddle.net/d72wvjjn/2/

please tell me how to resolve the issue ??

Comment: Add another span for the first part of the text.  You're removing .headscreentext when you update the first one.

Comment: @wwwmarty could you please let me know how todo that

Comment: You could use `replace` method. Something like http://jsfiddle.net/d72wvjjn/6/

Answer (score 4):

```
var headScreenText = $('.headscreentext');
$('.headloctext').text('Some new text ').append(headScreenText);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/d72wvjjn/5)**

Comment: Thank you could you please tell me how to resolve using a span , i was trying this way http://jsfiddle.net/d72wvjjn/7/

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<h1 class="headerLogo headerLogoWith"><span class="headvendnametext">Pick</span><br>
<i><span class="headloctext">Location Name</span> <span class="headscreentext">ScreenName</span></i></h1>
```

That should solve the problem. Simple, yes?